# Is a B-Spline always made up of Bezier curve segments?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, spline, bezier-curve

According to what I have read, a B-Spline curve is made up of segments, with each segment controlled by '*k*' control points (where *k* is the order of the curve). Also, a B-Spline curve can be formed by gluing Bezier curves together and constraining some of its control points.
 
More specifically, '*S*' Bezier curves, each of order '*k*', can be glued together to form a 'C^a' continuous B-Spline with order '*k'* and *kS*-*(a+1)(S-1)* control points.
**My question is:**
Is the converse true? Is every segment of a B-Spline (defined by the parameter between two consecutive knot values) an individual Bezier curve, or can be represented as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, a B-Spline curve can be formed by gluing Bezier curves together and constraining some of its control points

You don't need no constraining. Given $n$ arbitrary Bezier curves there exist a (probably discontinuous) BSpline curve which coincide with the union of the Bezier curves in any given order.

> Is the converse true? Is every segment of a B-Spline (defined by the parameter between two consecutive knot values) an individual Bezier curve, or can be represented as one

Yes, if the spline degree is $d$, you can perform knot insertion until all distinct knots has multiplicity $d+1$. The control points of the resulting BSpline curve coincides with those of the individual Bezier curves.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this topic, but how do we prove that those individual curves are Bezier curves?

Answer (score 1):

A B-spline curve is basically a piecewise continuos polynomial curve. So, each segment of a B-spline curve is a polynomial curve of a certain degree. A Bezier curve is also a polynomial curve and any polynomail curve can be represented as a Bezier curve. Therefore, each segment of a B-spline curve can be represented as a Bezier curve.